# MySQL average datediff per month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have for example following databse:

```
date1      | date2      | datediff
2016-11-02 | 2016-11-05 | 3
2016-11-08 | 2016-11-10 | 2
2016-11-01 | 2016-11-05 | 4
2016-11-09 | 2016-11-09 | 0
2016-11-15 | 2016-11-20 | 5
```

I get the datediff with following sql:

```
select 
datediff(date2, date1)
from table
```

Now I need the average datediff for each month,
in this case for
2016-11: 2.8

Thanks in advance, Patrick.

Comment: What if date1 & date2 is having different months ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use month(), AVG and group by

```
select year(date1), month(date1), avg(datediff(date2, date1))
from my_table 
group by year(date1), month(date1)
;
```

Comment: This answer makes more sense

Comment: don't thought that it would be so easy

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `group by`:

```
select year(date1), month(date1), AVG(datediff(date2, date1))
from table
group by year(date1), month(date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select AVG(datediff(date2, date1))
from table
group by year(date1), month(date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last day of the month for any date / time value with the [`LAST_DAY()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day). (It sounds more apocalyptic than it is.) That's useful for grouping.

So, try

```
 SELECT LAST_DAY(date1) month_ending, AVG(DATEDIFF(date2,date1)) datediff
   FROM table
  GROUP BY LAST_DAY(date1)
  ORDER BY LAST_DAY(date1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(datediff(date2, date1))as difference
from table
group by year(date1),month(date1)
```